# Does this object have a category-theoretic name?

Tags: terminology, category-theory, function-and-relation-composition

I have morphisms:

$$
f : A \to B \\
g : B \to C
$$

The composition is:

$$
g \circ f : A \to C
$$

In the function $(g \circ f)$ we call $A$ the domain and $C$ the codomain (or range).

I'm working in Haskell code, and in my application the type we pass through $(B)$ is particularly important.  Does this intermediate value have a standard name?

Comment: Why is "the range of $f$" or "the domain of $g$" not what you want?

Comment: @mt_ I was hoping there was a standard one-word thing I could call the type in code (e.g. "pseudodomain") to make the code easier to read.

Comment: I don't think such a word exists, could be wrong of course.  A word that even Haskell programmers like yourself haven't heard of isn't likely to  make your code clearer imho.

Comment: @mt_ Well I've got to call it something :)  I was wondering if it had a standard name I should use... I guess that means I get to invent it!

Comment: if you want to make your code clear and readable, I suggest calling it `domain(g)` because anyone, Haskell programmer or not, will know what that means.

Comment: One usually says that the morphism _factors through_ B.  Perhaps this could inspire a suitable name.

Comment: Of course the reason that B has no name is that there is no B! If all you have is the "result" of the composition there is no way to know what B was or what f and g were individually. If on the other hand you do have f and g you also have B.

Comment: @Adeel  Thanks.  I'm calling it the factordomain, and that seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: @MikeIzbicki Maybe you want to answer your own question so that it gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Adeel's comment above, I've been calling $B$ the "factor domain."